# Building a new dataset

Tags: dataframe

I want to take data from one set and enter it into another empty set.

So, for example, I want to do something like:

```
if ([i,x] > 9){
   new_data$House[y,x] <- data[i,2]
}
```

but I want to do it over and over, creating new rows in `new_data`.
How do I keep adding data to `new_data` and overriding/saving the new row?

Essentially, I just want to know how to "grow" an empty data set. 
Please ignore any errors in the code, it is just an example and I am still working on other details.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `r` language, I presume you are looking for `rbind`:

```r
new_data = NULL # define your new dataset

for(i in 1:nrow(data)) # loop over row of data
{
    if(data[i,x] > 9) # if statement for implementing a condition
    {
       new_data = rbind(new_data,data[i,2:6]) # adding values of the row i and column 2 to 6
    }
}
```

At the end, new_data will contain as many rows that satisfy the `if` statement and each row will contain values extracted from column 2 to 6.

If it is what you are looking for, there is various ways to do that without the need of a `for` loop, as an example:

```r
new_data = data[data[i,x]>9,2:6]
```

If this answer is not satisfying for you, please provide more details in your question, include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data and the expected output